# The product of two normal Chernikov-by hypercentral sub-groups

Tags: group-theory

> **(P. Hall result)** If H, K are two normal hypercentral subgroups
>   of a group; then HK is hypercentral.

We say that a group G is Chernikov-by-hypercentral if there is normal subgroup N of G such that N is Chernikov group and G/N is hypercentral.

If H, K are two normal Chernikov-by-hypercentral is HK is also Chernikov-by-hypercentral? I think it is true but i do not know how to prove it.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that this question is not suitable for mathoverflow, but the general guideline is to wait a while (perhaps a day), and if you get no answer here, then try mathoverflow.